# PrimeNG components d.ts files does not contain @Input @Output metadata

Tags: typescript, webstorm, visual-studio-code, primeng

I am experimenting with PrimeNG library and Angular 2.0. I am using Typescript and I have noticed that all *.d.ts files for PrimeNG components does not contain standard Angular 2.0 metadata like @Input() @Output().

Example ***dialog.d.ts***:

```
export declare class Dialog implements AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {
    private el;
    private domHandler;
    private renderer;
    header: string;
    draggable: boolean;
    resizable: boolean;
...
```

You can notice that `dragable: boolean;` does not have @Input() metadata above it which lead to editor not showing intelisence that this component has such bindable property. Example `<p-dialog dragable...? ></p-dialog>`

In both WebStorm 2016 or Visual Studio Code when creating Angular 2.0 template and try to use PrimeNG components I don't get any intelisence for the API which this component is exposing.

Question is why *.d.ts files does not contain metadata ? Is there a good workaround to get code hinting work without this metadata in the *.d.ts files ?

Comment: And your question is? But generally speaking -- contact the author of that package and ask if he can add such info etc.

Comment: I have added a question. After more searching I think generally it could be just a side effect of other problem which is that *.d.ts files actually can not contain metadata at all  !? Can this be confirmed by someone please ?

Comment: This information is not, and should not be, and does not need to be, part of TypeScript types. It is metadata, which you will find in `foo.component.metadata.json`.